# Recognizing back click on WP7 Camera

Tags: windows-phone-7, camera, back

In my WP7 application I need to the user to take a picture before arriving to page X. So on my main page, when the user click the button to navigate to page X, I call page X with the following constructor:

```
Public Sub New()
    Me.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
    InitializeComponent()
    Me.Camera = New CameraCaptureTask
End Sub
```

and then on the "loaded" event I call to Me.Camera.Show()

On the "Camera.Completed" I show the page again (Me.Visibility = Visibility.Visible).

Now for the problem - 
If the user, while on te camera screen, click the phone's back button, the page that appears is Page X without the mandatory picture while I want (and the user must have meant) to go back to the main page.

So how can I override this behavior and make the app go back to main page if clicking back from the camera screen?

Thanks,

Alon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Visual Basic, so I can't really provide any code. However, what I would do is check if the [PhotoResult's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.photoresult%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) stream is `null` when the `Completed` event is fired. If it is null, then a picture has not been taken and you can prompt the user to take a picture (or whatever you want to do). If it is not null, then carry on as normal. 
Alternatively, you could take a look at the PhotoResult's [TaskResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.taskresult%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) property to determine what happened.

Comment: Looking for TaskResult not TaskResult.OK should do it just fine.

Comment: Yes, simple and elegant (TaskResult <> OK does the job). Sometimes the simplest things are just right near your toes... :)